What should I do if I am being guided to walk in circles?
My primary and secondary supervisors, along with four students, published a paper in March 2019. My primary supervisor asked me to implement the paper as part of my PhD.
I studied the paper well and asked my primary supervisor two very specific questions along with detailed descriptions and diagrams. His reply was that he is not clear about the mathematical notations used in the paper. So, he sent me a PDF  with an alternate explanation (which I already knew very well) without addressing my specific questions.
Then I emailed my secondary supervisor. After three weeks of repeating the same email at least six times, he replied back with a hand-drawn diagram (devoid of any description) with no mention of my specific questions.
Both my primary and secondary supervisors insisted on studying their versions of alternate explanations and asking back more questions.
Then I emailed 2/4 other authors, including the 1st author. They work for various companies like NVIDIA, Tesla, etc. They never replied back. The other two have no publicly available email IDs.
Issue (1): Those alternate explanations supplied by my professor are not helping me implement the algorithm. Because (a) there are ambiguities in the description in the paper; (b) there are missing contexts in the pseudocode of the algorithm.
Issue (2): They were the PIs of the paper. So, I cannot go to someone else.
What should I do now?

What is the timescale here? A month, half a year, or more?

@MisterMiyagi, I started working on implementing this paper on 13-oct-2024. I should finish it by January 2025, including a detailed testing.

This is really individualized, but to be honest, is two months that long?

You're learning a core lesson of a PhD: when you're doing novel research, there's nobody to give you the answer, so you'll have to try stuff yourself.

Time for an in-person meeting. It is hard to discuss things like this by e-mail, especially if they are not great about reading and responding to e-mails. You need to spend time at the whiteboard together. You may need a few sessions over a few days so that if they tell you try something, you can do it and follow up within a few hours. This will force them to dig in, rather than just telling you something vague so that you will go away.
If you are fully remote and cannot meet in person, then that is the underlying problem. Fully-remote works well in many cases, but it does not seem like it is working well in your case. All decisions have consequences, and the decision to work remotely (if indeed that's what you're doing) seems like it is having serious consequences in this case.
Before this meeting, implement your "best guess" of the algorithm. If you there are ambiguities in the paper, implement both alternatives. If the authors claim they did A but you think it should be B, try that too. You don't necessarily need to reproduce the exact numbers from the paper so long as you get something reasonably close. But it is much, much easier to discuss stuff like this when you have a working version of the code and can easily run experiments, rather than when it is just in idea land. And your advisor will also be more motivated to help you when it is "I have the code working except for this issue" rather than "I'll start thinking about maybe beginning to possibly start writing a bit of the code at some point once I understand this issue."

+1 especially for the "have a best guess implementation" ready. Some of the ambiguities might even go away when you go through the trouble of getting feedback from your home-grown implementation. OP's remaining questions will be much more relevant for the eventually needed discussion.

It's easy to get trapped in cycles of unproductive e-mails-- I feel like I learn this lesson about once every three years, myself.  I add only that if in person meetings are just not possible, then video conferences can be a useful middle ground.  The live-ness of the conversation, the ability to interrupt in real time, see body language, and share screens and documents is much more useful than a 20th century phone call, and infinitely superior to endless rounds of e-mails.  (But's not as good as being physically present.)
